# Better alternative to mysqldump

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql

Is there a better (free) alternative to mysqldump? Because lately i'm having problems with corrupted database dumps. Mysqldump creates faulty sql code and when trying to restore the DB it fails with a lot of sql errors

So is there something better?

Answer (score 9):

mysqldump is the officially supported application for dumping MySQL databases. If you are getting faulty SQL code, then you should bring this to the attention of the developers by raising tickets.

I have used mysqldump over many years and never had any issues with it. Every single time it produced an output that differed from my expectations it was down to me having made a mistake. Maybe you should raise the specific problem you have on dba.stackexchange.com?

Comment: wolfgangsz, The webpage listed in your profile links to a drupal install.

Answer (score 0):

At first - i don't think some other app could be more safety then mysqldump.
At second - i know next alternatives to mysqldump:

1. [mydumper](http://vbtechsupport.com/1695/)
2. [Percona XtraBackup](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup)
3. [sypex dumper](http://sypex.net/en/products/dumper/compare/) (work from command line too - recommended)